# Parameter estimation for HMM with different emission distribution for different states

Tags: optimization, hidden-markov-model

I am trying to solve a parameter estimation problem where a HMM have different emission distribution for different states (i.e. Gaussian for one state and exponential for the other). However most standard method that uses EM algorithm assumes the same distribution (e.g. only Gaussian), where the M step can be explicitly evaluated.

I am not too sure how the M step is evaluated in the case of multiple state-dependent emission distributions, and any help would be appreciated!